# Can you explain the result in this one, please?

Tags: integration, substitution

I tried complete the square, but it doesn't work

I got this:

$\int\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{3-2x-x^2}}$

And I know that the answer is:

$-{\sqrt{3-2x-x^2}}-\arcsin(\frac{x+1}{2})+c$

Comment: The correct answer seems to be $$-\sqrt{3-2x-x^2}-\arcsin((x+1)/2).$$ Complete the square inside the square root, and make a change of variables.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{x}{\sqrt{3-2x-x^2}}=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4-(x+1)^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-(x+1)^2}}$. Does it suffice now? By the way, the answer is wrong.

Comment: Why didn't completing the square work along with a standard trigonometric substitution?  Or better yet, use the way forward in the comment from @Asydot.

Comment: Yep the answer was wrong, sorry guys,

Comment: And I'm sorry again, but I'm stiil don't get it.
where goes the x after de minus en the comment of @Asydot?

Comment: I don't know how to reach the answer. I can't with this simple excercise

Comment: @user265955 $x=(x+1)-1$. ;)

Comment: @user265955 I think I should ask if you have learnt about trigonometric substitution or something like lab bhattacharjee answered there. If not, I think you may google it or seek it from books ;)

Answer (score 1):

As $$3-2x-x^2=2^2-(x+1)^2$$

start with $x+2=2\sin y$ where $-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies dx=2\cos y\ dy$

$$\int\dfrac{x\ dx}{\sqrt{3-2x-x^2}}=\int\dfrac{2(\sin y-1)2\cos y}{+2\cos y}\ dy=?$$